# Why Oracle's SQL Developer UX is so bad?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

- No ability to comment out inside lines (like `select /*name,*/ surname from users`), you need to constantly type on new line because of `--` operator
- When browsing in tableView/Data/Filter field doesn't support basic input commands (like Ctrl+Z). And many other fields too.
- Opens tableView just on single click on table / entering the first letter in list.
- By default opens every tableView in single tab
- It's not snappy (almost slow)
- Worksheets are not saved by default between application opening

Answer (score 1):

Don't follow this comment. You can use / * comments with no issues.

> No ability to comment out inside lines (like select /*name,*/ surname from users), you need to constantly type on new line because of -- operator

copy/paste/cut doesn't work for you ?

> When browsing in tableView/Data/Filter field doesn't support basic input commands (like Ctrl+Z). And many other fields too.

This is a preference.

> Opens tableView just on single click on table / entering the first letter in list.

Preference again

> By default opens every tableView in single tab

[image]

Not a very specific comment to find the issue you are seeing.

> It's not snappy (almost slow)

Comment: I'm aware of 2nd preference, but unable to find first one. Can you give a link/show it ?

Comment: both preferences mentioned are in that screenshot.

Comment: thanks. Ctrl+C works in Filter, but whyyyy the Ctrl+Z not working ?)

Comment: also why no shortcut to place /* */ comment ?

Comment: Just checked now and it's working fine. what version/ what java version/ what platform

Comment: No one ever asked/thought about it. Makes sense. I'll get it built.

Comment: Win 7 Enterprise SP1, Java 8.152, 18.2.0.183 of sql  developer. I feel it's not working on any windows, but may be wrong.

Comment: also why no saving worksheets silently on exit/periodically ?